# Speed of processing elements to a block of memory when executing operation

Tags: c++

Well actually why my cycle works without stopping??? it should made approximately 100 iterations but it doesn't stop, please help .
I took min_block_size this is 10% of my cache memory 1 level, and max_block_size this is 10% of my l2 cache memory!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#define MIN_BLOCK_SIZE 13108
#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE 104858
#define STEP 1024
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");


    int i, j, c, b;
    clock_t c1, c2;
    int*p = (int*) malloc(MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    int tmp = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER start, finish, freq;
    c1 = clock();
    int n = 0;
    for (b = 13108; b < 104858; b = +1024)
    {
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        for (c = 0; c <= b; c += sizeof (int))
        {
            tmp += *(int*) ((int) p + c);
            *(int*) ((int) p + c) = tmp;
        }
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&finish);
        double time = (finish.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double) freq.QuadPart;
        n++;
        cout << "Размер" << n << "блоков:" << (MIN_BLOCK_SIZE + 1024 * (n - 1)) << "KB" << endl;
        cout << "Время o6pаботки" << n << "блоков" << time * 1000000 << "мкс" << endl;
        cout << "время обработки одного елемента" << time * 1000000000 / (MIN_BLOCK_SIZE + 1024 * (n - 1)) << "наносек" << endl;
    }
    c2 = clock();
    cout << "All the time is" << c2 - c1 << "sec";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tmp += *(int*)((int)p + c);` There's a good chance that converting the pointer to `int` loses information, and you read from (and then write to) memory you don't own. What's wrong with using `int *q = p`, and `++q;`?

Comment: You have several questions which have been answered and for which you didn't accept an answer. Please accept an answer when it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
for (b = 13108; b < 104858; b = +1024)
```

implies a loop that runs forever, as `b` is reset to `+1024` (does not have 1024 added!).  Presumably you meant to write:

```
for (b = 13108; b < 104858; b += 1024)
```

Comment: Good eye. I autocorrected that when skimming (but there were no spaces then).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Fortunately, I mostly only autocorrect my own code.  It helps a lot if I leave it for a bit and then go back and look at it, so that I don't read what I meant to write instead of what I actually wrote. :-)

Comment: well thank you, i haven't see that

Comment: I use spaces around assignments, that makes it much easier to find such typos if they ever occur.

Comment: well but why the time is increasing after elements stored in cache, when more elements stored they time should decrease but it increases